# Find filenames with uppercase extension

Tags: bash, bash-scripting, sh

How can I find all the files with their extension in uppercase recursively in a directory.

I've tried :

```
$ find -name "*.[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]"
```

Seems to work but of course this does not check files with more than 3 letters after the last dot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following works for simple cases:

```
find -name "*.*[A-Z]*" ! -name "*.*[^A-Z]*"
```

It is liable to fail for files with two or more dots in the name. For this case you need to use Regular Expressions, eg with `grep`:

```
find | grep '\.[A-Z][A-Z]*$'
```

or `egrep`:

```
find | egrep '\.[A-Z]+$'
```

Following Kamil Maciorowski's comment, the answer could be made locale-independent by using `[:upper:]` in place of `A-Z`, as in:

```
find | egrep '\.[[:upper:]]+$'
```

I'm afraid that we native-English speakers can easily forget such matters.

Comment: Avoid `[A-Z]`. [How to make `grep '[A-Z]'` independent of locale?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6800018)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - A valid point, but it was the questioner who originally suggested that `[A-Z]` was what he wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use RE with -regex option

```
find -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*\.[A-Z]{3}'
```

There are some points using RE with find, I learned that in a pt_BR book.

`-regex` option wants to match the whole path, so the `.*` matches everything
before the actual RE you want to match.
If the RE can be in the middle, another `.*` must be place at the end.

The `-regextype` tells which meta-characters must be escaped or not.

What I know is that in Unix/BSD `find -E` allows all meta-characters
unescaped, and in GNU/Linux the same is `-regextype posix-extended`,
`-regextype posix-awk` or `-regextype posix-egrep`.

Comment: More info on the manual https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Regular-Expressions

Answer (score 0):

I've recently come across a similar problem - searching for files that have **at least one uppercase character in their extension**. My pure Bash solution to the problem is:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# find files with at least one uppercase character in an extension

shopt -s nullglob dotglob globstar
for file in ./**/*; do
    if [[ -f $file ]]; then
        file_basename=$(basename "$file")
        ext="${file_basename#*.}"
        [[ $ext =~ [[:upper:]] ]] && echo "$file"
    fi
done
```